# What does GNU Guix need Nix programs for?

Tags: makefile, gnu, configure, nix

I'm attempting to compile GNU Guix from source for non-root package management. When running configure with `--disable-daemon`, I get the following error:

```
configure: error: Nix programs not found; please install Nix or use `--with-nix-prefix'
```

As I understand it, Nix is a whole other package manager. Why does Guix need this? Is it built on top of Nix? Most importantly, can I compile Guix without Nix dependence?

Comment: I could be horribly wrong here, but i think GNU Guix is effectively doing the same as Nix and even using a lot of it (the daemon, probably libstore). AFAIK it started of as "just" a different language / syntax (scheme instead of Nix language)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guix is based on and uses core components from Nix.

From the [Guix "About"](https://www.gnu.org/software/guix/about/) page (emphasis mine):

> GNU Guix provides state-of-the-art package management features such as
>   transactional upgrades and roll-backs, reproducible build
>   environments, unprivileged package management, and per-user profiles.
>   ***It uses low-level mechanisms from the Nix package manager***, but
>   packages are defined as native Guile modules, using extensions to the
>   Scheme language—which makes it nicely hackable.